# How to make text revealed when hovering?

Tags: jquery

I found this effect done in Flash. Is there a similar method to solve this in JavaScript?
Look at the link below and hover over 2013.

http://www.iflymagazine.com/?locale=no_en

Comment: Yes there is nothing on that page that couldn't be done via Javascript, images and CSS. If you're using jquery then the slideup and slidedown functions would get you a long way towards that effect.

Comment: there are piles of plugins that can do this kind of thing. You just have to choose one and develop a solution around it.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a very basic example:](http://jsfiddle.net/3kN7P/)

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id='2'><span>2</span></div>
<div id='0'><span>0</span></div>
<div id='1'><span>1</span></div>
<div id='3'><span>3</span></div>

div{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    color: white;
    background: red;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}
span{
    font-size:125px;
    line-height:-10px;
}

$(function () {
    $('div').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).stop(true).animate({backgroundColor: 'white', color: 'red'}, 500, 'easeInQuint');
    });

    $('div').mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).stop(true).animate({backgroundColor: 'red', color: 'white'}, 500, 'easeInQuint');
    });
});
```

it does not have the slide effect you want. To do that I imagine that you would have to mess around with multiple elements and swap them in and out.

EDIT: I took another look at what you wanted and I made [this:](http://jsfiddle.net/a4tFB/)

```
.wrapper{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
.number{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    color: white;
    background: red;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    z-index:2;
}
.text{
    position:absolute;
    display:inline-block;
    z-index:1;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    color: black;
    background: gray;
    font-size:8pt;
}
.spnNum{
    font-size:125px;
    line-height:-10px;
}

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='number' id='2'><span class='spnNum'>2</span></div>
    <div class='text' id='t2'>
        <span> Text Goes in here to be displayed when the number is hidden</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='number' id='0'><span class='spnNum'>0</span></div>
    <div class='text' id='t0'>
        <span> Text Goes in here to be displayed when the number is hidden</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='number' id='1'><span class='spnNum'>1</span></div>
    <div class='text' id='t1'>
        <span> Text Goes in here to be displayed when the number is hidden</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='number' id='3'><span class='spnNum'>3</span></div>
    <div class='text' id='t3'>
        <span> Text Goes in here to be displayed when the number is hidden</span>
    </div>
</div>

$(function () {
    $('.number').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).slideUp(200);
    });

    $('.text').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).prev().slideDown();
    });

});
```

It can be a bit buggy if you try and move between the numbers too quickly and this only gets worse the slower the animation is. but it does get you real close I think to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank's this was a good start for me. I will now try to find a solution for my site. What I want is to reveal text behind the squears. I will search the web for more solutions as well. :-)

Comment: I can mock something up with multiple elements if you don't mind waiting a bit.